# stop a browser from opening flash images

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an flash document and I only want it to open IE (and not Firefox or Chrome for example).

How to do this in .NET using C#.

I don't want Firefox or Chrome to download that image on a button click event and i want only IE to run this...how do i achieve this?

I have tried to request the browser type and wrote a code to run only when it is IE bu this doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the code that doesn't work? No one here is a psychic.

Comment: This is a bit confused - is it an _image_ or a flash file? I don't know what a "flash image" is.

Comment: @Oded [this is a flash image](http://www.fightersgeneration.com/np6/char2/flash-mkvsdc-white.jpg)

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen - So it is!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want your server-side ASP.NET code to send a different response to the client based on what browser it is?

This article might help: [Obtaining your User's Browser Information](https://web.archive.org/web/20210619191145/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/121400-1.shtml)

In C#, something like this can be used to detect IE:

```
if (Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT").Contains("MSIE")) {
  // is IE
} else {
  // is not IE
}
```

but note that users can set their browsers to use a different user agent string, so this isn't 100% reliable.